# Calling ruby_init and ruby_finalize multiple times

Tags: c++, ruby, googletest

I'm currently trying to test some Ruby (2.3) C API with google test.

But my tests are crashing because I've created a fixture that calls `ruby_init` on setup and `ruby_finalize` on tear down.

I've then created a "singleton" inside the fixture which solves the problem, but I would like to know if there's another, simpler, way to do it.

I would like all my tests to run in a proper/clean VM.

Following is a simple example that reproduces the error:

```
#include <ruby.h>

int
main()
{
  ruby_init();
  ruby_finalize();

  ruby_init();
  ruby_finalize();
}
```

Error:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fa7f769a040 (LWP 6525))]
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007fa7f6305c5d in __GI_abort () at abort.c:90
#2  0x00007fa7f634aaad in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7fa7f645957b "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007fa7f6352298 in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7fa7f645ae88 "double free or corruption (!prev)") at malloc.c:5368
#4  0x00007fa7f635358c in _int_free (av=0x7fa7f668dc40 <main_arena>, p=0x7fa7f8023b50, have_lock=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4288
#5  0x00007fa7f7092a8d in objspace_xfree (objspace=0x7fa7f7fb3d20, ptr=0x7fa7f8023b60, old_size=<optimized out>) at gc.c:7720
#6  0x00007fa7f70a514f in rb_io_fptr_finalize (fptr=0x7fa7f8023b60) at io.c:4338
#7  0x00007fa7f70897b1 in run_final (objspace=0x7fa7f7fb3d20, zombie=140359397235560) at gc.c:2691
#8  finalize_list (objspace=objspace@entry=0x7fa7f7fb3d20, zombie=140359397235560) at gc.c:2707
#9  0x00007fa7f7089870 in finalize_deferred (objspace=objspace@entry=0x7fa7f7fb3d20) at gc.c:2728
#10 0x00007fa7f7094280 in rb_objspace_call_finalizer (objspace=0x7fa7f7fb3d20) at gc.c:2794
#11 rb_gc_call_finalizer_at_exit () at gc.c:2780
#12 0x00007fa7f76b97e2 in main ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `ruby_cleanup(0)` instead?

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/5b72097225797dfb91d4e3cbd4983bedf0eadb26/eval.c#L163), it looks like `ruby_finalize` just makes sure that the Ruby code finishes up (e.g. calling `at_exit` hooks, maybe killing any Ruby threads). Whereas `ruby_cleanup` calls finalize and then cleans up the VM itself.

**Edit:**

Based on my tests, this answer doesn't work (despite being accepted). You cannot restart the Ruby VM within the same process. The only workaround I could think of was to start the VM in a fork so that you can guarantee it gets completely cleaned up.

Comment: Ok ... seems to work. But valgrind complains a lot about lost records. I do not have so much lost record with ruby_finalize. thank you very much